# JS Different Kind of Redirection

Tags: javascript, html

I need to redirect a page using JS and I wonder how to do that? Assume I have following URL already opened in the browser which has few anchor tags,

```
file:///someDrive:/someFolder/index.html
```

One of anchor tag has onclick set to `redirect('login.html');` and when I press it it should redirect to,

```
file:///someDrive:/someFolder/login.html
```

How?

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript for that? Just `href="login.html"` should work afaik.

Comment: does "<input type='button'>" has href?

Comment: No. But you did not mention buttons. You said *anchor tags*.

Comment: It was an example. You didn't need to assume that. Anyway I found the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have a JavaScript function, you can do:

```
function redirect(page) {
    var href = window.location.href;
    // this will remove "/index.html" from the URL
    var path = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('/'));

    window.location.href = path + '/' + page;
    // or window.location.assign(path + '/' + page);
}
```

Still, for normal links, you don't need this, setting the correct `href` attribute is sufficient. Also, if you don't have a form, I would not use `<input type="button" />` but just `<button>`[*<sup>(docu)</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button).

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(page){
window.location = page;
}
</script>

<a onclick="redirect('http://www.google.com');"></a>
```

You may need to change window.location to window.location.href to support some other browsers.

Comment: That's easy. I can do that myself.